# B4A How to popup a message box on top of non-related apps

Tags: basic4android, vb4android

I need to run a service that notifies an android phone user with a button/messagebox that there is a message waiting for them in a background app.  I have a scheduler program that does this very thing.  Can someone help me with the code or point out some code that will do this?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE: Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help:)

Comment: I think you are asking for notification not msgbox I guess.